# Testing for Apex page action

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
<apex:page controller="MyController" 
       action="{!IF($Profile.Name != 'xyz', 
  URLFOR($Action.MyObj__c.List, $ObjectType.MyObj__c), NULL)}">

other markup goes here

 </apex:page>
```

As you can see here, I have a controller and a page that would be displayed only if the profile IS xyz. If the profile is NOT xyz, it takes them to the list view of the object.

Question: Will I be able to test this apex:page action (page redirect to list view) in a test class? If yes, how to do it? I know that we can only test "apex controller" code in the test class and not the "markup" code but wanted to be sure.

Comment: Nope you can't write a unit test for it. Functional testing is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought is that this isn't something to put through unit testing, but rather something to put through *functional testing*.

Selenium is a tool that can help out with this, and there a variety of tutorials and blog posts that can help get you started such as [this one by Jitendra Zaa](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/getting-started-with-selenium-and-salesforce-salesforce-automation-testing-video-tutorial-part-1/)

Comment: Thanks Derek, that's my thinking too. but wanted to be doubly sure that I'm not missing any "security aka profiles based" testing via unit tests.